# Microsoft graph not creating embed link for file

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

While posting request to microsoft graph:

```
POST 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/017_2018-08-12_18.47.27.jpg:/createLink'
content-type': 'application/json
{
  "type": "embed"
}
```

I am only getting

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#permission",
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.permission",
  "id": "5o98ENjWYH2pNK8wO5_d7QHUrdk",
  "roles": ["read"],
  "shareId": "s!AgDP2w-bgvZL****evpaN2yel",
  "link": {
    "type": "embed",
    "webUrl": "https://onedrive.live.com/embed?resid=4B****U"
```

But according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink), I should also get WebHtml with Iframe link not only webUrl, and this is what I am looking for so I can generate links for photos, and put them on website.

Am I doing something wrong or is there any way around so I can get same embed url that I can generate from manualy clicking in onedrive?

I'm using personal one drive account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying this out on the graph explorer does not work on the v1.0 endpoint for me. However using the beta endpoint does indeed return the `webHtml` property like as follows

Essentially what you would need to do is change the `v1.0` segment in the url to `beta`.

```
POST 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/drive/root:/017_2018-08-12_18.47.27.jpg:/createLink'
content-type': 'application/json
{
  "type": "embed"
}
```

And you should get back something like this

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#permission",
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.permission",
    "id": "p6z1ZAtRqKFwqHNVfaa6mPFQIyI",
    "roles": [
        "read"
    ],
    "shareId": "s!AorKRTkoJljsixZbAANWreQhS7gk",
    "expirationDateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "hasPassword": false,
    "link": {
        "type": "embed",
        "webUrl": "https://onedrive.live.com/embed?resid=EC5826283945CA8A%211430&authkey=!AFsAA1at5CFLuCQ",
        "webHtml": "<iframe src=\"https://onedrive.live.com/embed?resid=EC5826283945CA8A%211430&authkey=!AFsAA1at5CFLuCQ\" width=\"98\" height=\"120\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\"></iframe>"
    }
}
```